# Failed to enter Game Center Sandbox

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5, sandbox, game-center

When developing a game center app, I found the sandbox mode is very unpredictable. My game and two devices worked for a while in sandbox mode. After some code are modified (not game center related), recompiled and started debugging, then I get the famous "This game is not recognized by game center" message.

- Delete the app
- Sign out Game Center from the Game Center app
- Restart debugging the app

does *not* help.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

If you are sure you are using you're sandbox gamecenter account (signed out of GameCenter using the GameCenter app, signed back in using your in  development app when prompted), then I would  try the following.

1.Delete the old version of the app on the device(s) and simulator

2.Clean the project in Xcode

3.Redeploy the app to the simulator / devices(s)